# Tensorflow network diverges if reading/preprocessing is done on cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some code that reads images from a tensor record, preprocesses them (cropping, apply random hue/saturation etc., all through tensorflows own methods) and then uses `shuffle_batch_join` to generate batches.

```
  with tf.variable_scope('dump_reader'):
    all_files = glob.glob(dump_file + '*')
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(all_files, num_epochs=epochs)

    example_list = [read_tensor_record(filename_queue, image_size)
                for _ in range(read_threads)]

    return tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(example_list, batch_size=batch_size,
                                       capacity=min_queue_size + batch_size * 16,
                                       min_after_dequeue=min_queue_size)
```

This works well and leads to converging network when placing all operations on gpu. However, this is right now the bottleneck of my code and I'd like to speed it up by placing it on the cpu by wrapping this block in a `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):`. With this I have faster iterations (about 1/5th), but the network diverges after about 10 iterations, leading to a loss of NaN. When visually inspecting the samples created in the tensorboard, there is no apparent difference.

Why is the convergence behavior different on cpu vs gpu? How could I further investigate into this weird behavior?

Comment: This is very strange. My guess is that there's a bug in (or inconsistency between) the GPU and CPU implementations of one of the image processing ops. To investigate, I'd suggest: (1) constructing your session with `tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))` to see which ops are *actually* scheduled on the GPU in the working version, and then selectively moving them to CPU to see which one might be causing this.

Comment: @mrry good idea, I'll do that and open an issue on github once I find something.

Comment: Did you ever manage to localize this problem? I'm running into a similar issue (with TF 0.8.0), where my pipeline runs fine on the GPU but on CPUs it starts generating NaNs pretty frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar issue. In my case I had pinned the image transformation ops to the GPU, but the data was being fed from queues on the CPU. For me it was a mistake to pin the ops to the GPU, so I pinned them to the CPU with `with tf.device('/cpu:0')` and my numerical instability issues went away.

Notably, I had also run these image preprocessing steps on the GPU previously but was not using queues to load the data. I simply feed the data directly to the GPU via a placeholder and everything ran just fine.

It was only when I started using queues, and loaded those queues from independent threads that I started seeing this issue (I was able to use the queues in a sequential manner when I didn't load them from separate threads).

I don't have an exact answer as to what happened yet, but it does seem like making sure that the data and the image pre-processing ops are consistently placed on the same device is quite critical.